# how to configure servlet mapping

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, configuration

I have spring mvc application

if in web.xml i write so:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I go to `http://localhost:8080/Mvc/controllerPath/sayHello`
I see my page

if I write

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/controllerPath/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I go to `http://localhost:8080/Mvc/controllerPath/sayHello`  -  I see 404

I think you understood what I want.

Can you hel me?

**UPDATE**

controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controllerPath")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/sayHello")
    public String sayHello(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("name", "Vasya");
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

if I write

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Mvc/controllerPath*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

i see 404

Comment: Please post your controller code

Comment: request mapping is based on controller

Comment: Don't put your context path in the `url-pattern`.

Comment: Can you help rewrite right?

Answer (score 3):

If you remove:

```
@RequestMapping("/controllerPath")
```

to

```
@RequestMapping("/")
```

the new servlet mapping will work.

The reason for this is that whatever you have in the servlet mapping url is stripped before spring tries to match it to a controller.

For example, in your first url mapping with just `/` (and assuming your web appllication is deployed to `/mvc`), your path of `/mvc/controllerPath/sayHello` spring strips the url mapping away from the url and expects to find a controller that maps to `/controllerPath/sayHello`

When you change the url-pattern to /controllerPath, since will strip that as well and look for a controller that answers to just `/sayHello`, which your controller won't since it's expecting `/controllerPath/sayHello`

Comment: I want that dispatcher servlet handles requests only from this controller

Comment: I don't understand. Can you write what I need to write in web.xml? I don't want to change java code

Comment: If you don't want to change the java code, then leave the `url-pattern` as `/`

Comment: can you write whole servlet mapping - I don't understand you

Comment: It's so unusual to map as the root and strip away url pattern.

Comment: Leave you're servlet mapping as it is, since it's already working:  `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

Comment: no no no I want that **http://localhost:8080/Mvc/anotherControllerPath/sayHello** don't handles by dispatcher servler

Comment: You can't do that unless you change the Java code as I wrote in my answer.